# Solr search for hashtag or mentions

Tags: solr

We are using solr version 3.5 to search though Tweets, I am using `WordDelimiterFactory` with the following setting, to be able to search for `@username` or `#hashtags`:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" handleAsChar="@#"/>
```

I saw the following patch but this doesn’t seem to be working as I expected, am I missing something?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2059

But searching for `@username` is also returning results for just username or `#hashtag` is just returning result for hastag. How can I achieve this?

Entire Field Type:

```xml
<fieldType name="textnostem" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>

<fieldType name="textnostem" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>      
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="textnostem" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            handleAsChar="@#"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1" 
            catenateNumbers="1" 
            catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="0" 
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            handleAsChar="@#"
            />      
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Can you show the entire fieldType definition that you are using, so we can if other filters or tokenizers might be influencing you results?

Comment: Personally, I'd just add two fields to your index, one for a list of mentions, one for tags.  Parse these out of your tweets when you add them to the index.  That way you're not relying on new functionality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, so reading through the SOLR-2059 patch that you mentioned, it looks like they have replaced the `handleAsChar` attribute on the WordDelimiterFactory with the `types` attribute. Here is the specification for that attribute from the Analyzers, Tokenizers and Token Filters Solr Wiki page:

> **types="wdfftypes.txt"** allows customized tokenization for this filter. The file should exist in the solr/conf directory, and entries are of the form (without quotes) "% => ALPHA" or "\u002C => DIGIT". Allowable types are: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, SUBWORD_DELIM.

So then if we take this documentation, plus the example of the file from SOLR-2059, I would recommend the following:

`<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="twittertypes.txt"/>`

Then define the twittertypes.txt file as follows and place it in the same folder as your schema.xml file in your Solr instance (probably the conf folder).

```
 # A customized type mapping for WordDelimiterFilterFactory
 # the allowable types are: LOWER, UPPER, ALPHA, DIGIT, ALPHANUM, SUBWORD_DELIM
 #    
 # the default for any character without a mapping is always computed from 
 # Unicode character properties

 # Map the $, %, '.', and ',' characters to DIGIT 
 # This might be useful for financial data.
 @ => ALPHA
 \u0023 => ALPHA
```

Notice that you need to use the Unicode character (UTF-8) for the hash symbol, since it is treated as comment in the text file.

According to all of the documentation, this should fix your issue and treat the # and @ symbols as alpha characters, which will provide the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Paige, figured it out late last night, working as mentioned by you.

Comment: I did all of the above and restarted solr service, still search for #pizza and pizza yields the same result, any clues or any more step I should follow ?

Comment: Did you reindex your documents after making the configuration changes?  Any time you make changes in the schema.xml file that impact the way documents are indexed, you must reindex the documents for the changes to be reflected in the indexed terms.

Comment: Yes, I did `manage.py rebuild_index` and `manage.py update_index` still the same, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build [a custom tokenizer](https://github.com/wetneb/lucene-twitter), which will parse usernames and hashtags as special tokens natively. You can then add a custom filter which normalizes the case of these usernames and hashtags (given that they are not case-sensitive), while leaving the other tokens untouched:

```
<fieldType name="text_twitter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="org.opentapioca.analysis.twitter.TwitterTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="org.opentapioca.analysis.twitter.TwitterLowercaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="org.opentapioca.analysis.twitter.TwitterTokenizerFactory" />
     <filter class="org.opentapioca.analysis.twitter.TwitterLowercaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```