# Solr WordDelimiterFilterFactory Dollar Sign, Percent Sign

Tags: solr, dollar-sign

When I query Solr for documents containing $99, it matches documents containing 99.

I can see that WordDelimiterFilterFactory producing a term text 99 from $99. How can I tell WordDelimiterFilter not to do that at the query phase?

Similar problem exists for percent sign (searching for %33 matches documents containing 33).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post your field definition in your schema.xml?

Comment: Please see this previous question/answer, it is asking the same thing, just for # and @ symbols - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299614/solr-search-for-hashtag-or-mentions

Comment: Thanks. It works as suggested there.