# Django-haystack search for #hashtag

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack, hashtag

I really have 0 experience in Haystack, but we use django-haystack for our search. For now the search works fine, but I just added #hashtags to the site and I would like the search to work somehow different for hashtagged words.

What I have right now:

- The results of searching for "pizza" and "#pizza" are the same, I think this is happening because "#" is being omitted in the search as a character.

What I want to accomplish:

- The results of searching for "#pizza" should only containt the text "#pizza".

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: what do you mean by exact ?

Comment: you said if you search #pizza should only contain the text #pizza, you can use exact or iexact function for that?

Comment: Oh, yes, but in this case the whole search thing using haystack with solr works different than Django querys.

Comment: Can you post your Solr schema.xml and which Solr field you are querying? Also are you indexing hashtags as separate field or is it part of a text field?

Comment: @arun: my schema is posted here, I don't think it's different from default [schema.xml](http://pastie.org/6345554). Hashtags are within the text.

Comment: I actually found this, seems to be the answer [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299614/solr-search-for-hashtag-or-mentions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people have [modified WordDelimiterFilterFactory and WordDelimiterFilter to handle @ and #-characters as digits](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/tokenizing-twitter-posts-lucene). Maybe that can work for you too?