# Want solr to find every document with just c#

Tags: solr, solr4

I believe the tokenizers strip out the hash, leaving just c, so it shows every document with c  in it.  I wanted to know how do you stop the striping of the hash mark.  Do I have to write a different tokenizer, or is there a simplier solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very easy thing to do and there are many different ways to achieve this. I would suggest you to refer the following articles to brush up your knowledege on Solr analyzers, etc before starting.

To answer your question, you can stop for stripping of the "#" character by defining a fieldtype in solr schema using a WhitespaceTokenizerFactory for the analysis.. The field will look like so..

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Please refer to the following articles for more information.

1. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers%2C+Tokenizers%2C+and+Filters
2. [Solr search for hashtag or mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299614/solr-search-for-hashtag-or-mentions)